# A Simple TCP Protocol to Transfer a "Large" Data File to a Server

Tags: sockets, tcp, protocols, network-protocols

***MESSAGE TO DOWN VOTERS:*** Please read the question, I am working on a small embedded device. If you are not familar with the limitations of such a device, then please move onto another question instead of down voting!!!!

I am working with a small embedded device that has limited memory and I need to send a large file to a server from this device. Hence I cannot *easily* use HTTP POST which requires me to load the entire file into memory before sending.

The embedded device has UDP and TCP sockets, but to send a HTTP POST for example, I need to create a string that contains the HTTP HEADERS and the Data. As the device does not have the HTTP Protocol or other protocols available as APIs.

Can someone recommend a protocol I could use to perform the process of "streaming" or sending the data in parts to the server?

The protocol needs to be relatively simple and not use up many memory resources, and if you know of a library designed for small embedded device that would be good also. The protocol should also be simple to implement on the receiving server, preferable running .Net

Comment: HTTP POST does not require you to load the entire file into memory before sending.

Comment: As stated in my question, I need to create the HTTP POST packet from the the ground up as I am using a small embedded device that does not have the HTTP Protocol implemented. Of course you are correct, but you are likely talking about how you use it on a powerful operating system that has  API to use that handles all of this. I am coding in raw C, with an RTOS that offers no such features.

Comment: Explains nothing. You still don't have to load the entire file into memory, and if that is your only objection to using HTTP POST, the problem is solved. You could also use HTTP PUT. Being rude to people who are trying to help you isn't a rational strategy.

Comment: EJP, I appreciate your efforts in answering my question. But as stated in my question, I only have TCP available....for anything above this on the protocol stack, I have to create my self. Perhaps I misunderstanding you and you do in fact have a solution, if that is the case, then please can you explain to me what I need to do? I am coding in ANSI C, and have a TCP Socket...where do I go from here?

Comment: How was I rude to you? I was very polite in my response to you. As for the down voters, they are not trying to help, they are just voting down and moving on. If they were trying to help, they would ask a question to better understand.

Comment: Just trying to understand, why is "streaming" a requirement? wouldn't transferring the file to server suffice?

Comment: It may not be a requirement. Streaming is a common programming pattern to solve such issues, but it may not be needed here. This is why I said "streaming" and sending in my question. I have updated the title to be clearer. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I am working with a small embedded device that has limited memory and I need to send a large file to a server from this device. Hence **I cannot easily use HTTP POST which requires me to load the entire file into memory before sending**.

No, `POST` does not require that.  All it requires is that the HTTP `Content-Length` header that you send matches the number of bytes that you send for the actual file data.  Or you can use HTTP 1.1's `chunked` transfer encoding, which does not use the `Content-Length` header (so you don't need to know the file size ahead of time).  `POST` (or HTTP, for that matter) has no concept of *HOW* you send the bytes in your code.  So all would have to do is read the file data in a loop, using an appropriate-sized memory buffer, sending the content of that buffer over the socket after each read, until you hit EOF.

For example (pseudo-code):

```
sckt = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)
connect(sckt, "hostname", 80)
send(sckt, "POST /resource HTTP/1.0\r\n")
send(sckt, "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n"); // or the actual file type
send(sckt, "Content-Length: " + string(the file size) + "\r\n")
send(sckt, "\r\n")

byte buffer[256] // use whatever buffer size is appropriate for your device
do
{
    numread = read(file, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    if (numread <= 0) break;
    send(sckt, buffer, numread);
}
while (true);

read HTTP response from sckt ...
```

Or:

```
sckt = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)
connect(sckt, "hostname", 80)
send(sckt, "POST /resource HTTP/1.1\r\n")
send(sckt, "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n"); // or the actual file type
send(sckt, "Transfer-Encoding: chunked\r\n")
send(sckt, "\r\n")

byte buffer[256] // use whatever buffer size is appropriate for your device
char hex[12]
do
{
    numread = read(file, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    if (numread <= 0) break;

    sprintf(hex, "%x", numread);
    send(sckt, string(hex) + "\r\n")
    send(sckt, buffer, numread)
    send(sckt, "\r\n")
}
while (true);

send(sckt, "0\r\n");
send(sckt, "\r\n");

read HTTP response from sckt ...
```

Even powerful desktop PCs have to do it this way, since an entire file usually cannot be put into the kernel buffer at one time anyway, so sending has to be looped accordingly.

> The embedded device has UDP and TCP sockets, but to send a HTTP POST for example, I need to create a string that contains the HTTP HEADERS and the Data.

You **DO NOT** have to send everything at one time in a single string.  You can break it up into multiple strings/sends as needed.  TCP is a streaming transport, it doesn't care how many sends you perform, as long as the bytes you send are in the correct order.  You could send 1 byte at a time for all it cares (though that would not be very efficient, but it would work).

> As the device does not have the HTTP Protocol or other protocols available as APIs.

It doesn't need to.  Since HTTP sits on top of TCP, and you have access to a TCP socket API, you can implement HTTP manually.

> Can someone recommend a protocol I could use to perform the process of "streaming" or sending the data in parts to the server?

HTTP already does exactly that.

> The protocol needs to be relatively simple and not use up many memory resources, and if you know of a library designed for small embedded device that would be good also. The protocol should also be simple to implement on the receiving server, preferable running .Net

HTTP is perfectly fine for that.

Comment: Thanks Remy. I really appreciate your detailed and insightful response. The reason I asked this question was because I did understand everything fully and was needing to be informed. You took the time to correct my assumptions and provide an answer.